# ExtJS: Sprite of type 'image': how to change pixels?

Tags: javascript, canvas, extjs, sprite

HTML element 'Canvas' provide functions getImageData and putImageData, so it is possible to read as well as to modify image-data. I need this functionality in an ExtJS (Sencha,version 5.1) project. I have to use a sprite of type 'image'. But I can't find any functions addressing neither access to pixels nor access to undrlying canvas, if such is used. Is there an another approach to achieve this?

with regards

Rafal Ziolkowski

Comment: Yes that is what `getImageData` and `putImageData` are for. Eg `dat = ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1); dat.data[0] = 255;dat.data[1] = 200;dat.data[2] = 55;dat.data[3] = 155; ctx.putImageData(dat,0,0);` Get the top left pixel and sets Red to 255, Green to 200, Blue to 55 and Alpha to 155 then puts the data back onto the canvas.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using ExtJS by Sencha, and have image as an sprite of type 'image'. To use these methods, I need access to html-canvas element. I even don't know if Sprite and the Draw-package are using html-canvas and if there is an access to this element.

Comment: If the browser supports canvas and the sprite is not SVG based it uses a canvas. You will have to inspect the draw surface for the canvas, if it is hidden via closure you will have to inspect the source and see if they provide access. But i imagine the canvas is public and easy to find

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is draw your sprites onto a canvas? From a browse of the ext js code there is a Ext.draw.engine.Canvas component which I believe uses a html canvas element. In this class you may be able to do what you want and get image data. If not you can always go and grab the element it renders and call the appropriate getImageData and putImageData. Hope this helps.

```
drawContainer = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Container', {
   items: [{
      mySprite
   }]
});
// after render
surface = drawContainer.getSurface();
surface.flatten(size, surface); // returns the drawn image data
// do this or get the element
canvas = surface.el.down('canvas');
```

not sure if this is what you want but hope it helps. Consult the documentation theres plenty of information on drawing sprites.
[senchadocs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.draw.Container)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?